# How to declare variables from DB in MySQLi (procedural)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Good Day,

I'm just a newbie in `MySQLi`. But I have a strong background in MySQL. Here's the thing. In MySQL, this is how I declare and retrieve variables from DB (database) of the clients' data:

Figure 1:

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Date of Birth:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Birthplace:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Gender:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Email Add:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Contact#:</strong></th>
<th><strong>Address:</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <?php

    $sql=mysql_query("--Sample Query using Inner Join to retrieve values taken from 3 tables on DB");
    $counter=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $cname  =   $row['name'];
        $cbday  =   $row['birthday'];
        $pob    =   $row['pob'];
        $cgen   =   $row['gender'];
        $email  =   $row['email'];
        $contact=   $row['contact'];
        $add    =   $row['address'];

            if($counter%2)
            {
            ?>
            <tbody>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <td><?php echo $cname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cbday; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $pob; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cgen; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contract; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $add; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php
        $counter++;
        }//while-end
        ?>

</table>
```

See how I placed the fetched value to a table on the index page? That is also under the `mysql_fetched_array()`. I used echo then the name of the variable I stated to call all `$row['values']`;

But when I checked the MySQLi tutorial, this is how a they used the `mysql_fetched_array()`:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

My question is, is it just the same with MySQL to name a variable in MySQLi? the way I did to Figure 1? [please see the code above.]

Also, to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` works very much like that of `mysql_fetch_assoc` only with an (i) could be added into it? Or these two bears different thing?

Comment: Do you want Figure 1 to use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: @Utkarsh exactly... :) is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Mysqli is an extension only

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
 <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><strong>Name:</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Date of Birth:</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Birthplace:</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Gender:</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Email Add:</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Contact#:</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Address:</strong></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php
    mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
        $sql=mysqli_query("--Sample Query using Inner Join to retrieve values taken from 3 tables on DB");
        $counter=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
            $cname  =   $row['name'];
            $cbday  =   $row['birthday'];
            $pob    =   $row['pob'];
            $cgen   =   $row['gender'];
            $email  =   $row['email'];
            $contact=   $row['contact'];
            $add    =   $row['address'];

                if($counter%2)
                {
                ?>
                <tbody>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <td><?php echo $cname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cbday; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pob; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cgen; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $contract; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $add; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php
            $counter++;
            }//while-end
            ?>

    </table>
```

I hope this helps you